# NetSuite Advanced PDF Dynamically Created in Script - Cannot Set <img> tag

Tags: css, xml, netsuite, suitescript

I am dynamically creating an Advanced PDF in script. I've created an XML string that I am then passing to NetSuite's XML to PDF API; nlapiXMLToPDF(xmlString).

I've added saved searches, tables, styling, and the xml string is parsing correctly.

I cannot add a logo in an  tag as I'm not sure how to drill into the file cabinet and store the 'src' of the image.

Has anyone had experience dynamically creating Advanced PDFs in NetSuite and pulling in the logo in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to include an image from the file cabinet? If you have the internal ID of the file in the variable  `fileID`, then you can use the following code:

```
var imageURL = nlapiLoadFile(fileID).getURL();
imageURL = nlapiEscapeXML(imageURL);
var xmlString = ... + '<div><img height="XXpx" width="XXpx" src="'+logoURL+'" /></div>' + ...;
var myPDF = nlapiXMLToPDF(xmlString);
```

If you want to use the Form Logo set on the Company Information page, then you can populate `fileID` using the following code:

```
var companyInfo = nlapiLoadConfiguration('companyinformation');
var fileID = companyInfo.getFieldValue('formlogo');
```

Then use the first code block to include the logo in `xmlString`.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Can you accept this answer so others can easily find the solution? Thanks!